# how to print output in txt file of for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def input_sentence():
    sppc = BetterICP(grammar2)
    with open("output.txt","w") as op:
        with open("input.txt", "r") as ins:
            array = []
            temp = []
            for line in ins:
                    array.append(line)
            for a in array:     
                op.write(str(sppc.parse(a.split()))
```

I need to write my output which I will get from `str(sppc.parse(a.split())` but not able to write it in file

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a ')' in op.write(str(sppc.parse(a.split()))

Comment: `<listiterator object at 0x104516a10><listiterator object at 0x104516910><listiterator object at 0x104516a10><listiterator object at 0x104516910><listiterator object at 0x104516a10><listiterator object at 0x104516910>` this is getting written in file

Comment: Try this:
`for a in array:`    
    `for item in sppc.parse(a.split()):`
        `op.write(str(item))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems sppc.parse returns an iterable object. Try to use:

```
for a in array:
    for b in sppc.parse(a.split())
        op.write(str(b))
```